# Showing $\sqrt{z}$ is holomorphic on the upper half plane and its image is the first quadrant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$f(z)=\sqrt{z}$$

be defined on the upper half plane $D=\{z \in \Bbb{C} : \text{Im}z>0\}$. I need to show $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ and that $f(D)$ is the first quadrant. To show holomorphicity, I appeal to the C-R equations. I set

$$\sqrt{x+iy}=u+iv$$

and solve for $x$ and $y$. I obtain

$$x+iy = u^2-v^2 + 2iuv$$

Which implies $x=u^2-v^2$ and $y=2uv$.

Then $x_u=y_v$ and $x_v=-y_u$ and the C-R equations are satisfied.

I am stuck as I haven't used that the domain is the upper half plane but I got the C-R equations.

Also, how do I show $f(D)=\{z \in \Bbb{C} : \text{Re}z>0, \text{Im}z>0\}$?

Comment: Your justification for $f$ being holomorphic works. For the second part, write $z$ in polar form and consider the effect $f$ has given $z$ is in $D$,

Comment: aha! Polar form, @jcneek thanks!! that totally makes!!

Comment: to be clear, this implies if $z=re^{i \theta}$ then $f(z)=\sqrt{r}e^{\frac{i \theta}{2}}$ where $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ thus cutting $\theta$ in half gives us $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$? @jcneek

Comment: If you haven't covered learned about branch cuts yet, then yea your argument works!

Comment: cool thanks!! @jcneek :)

Comment: One note here is that with the Cauchy-Riemann equations, it is the case that a function being holomorphic implies that the C-R equations hold, but showing that the C-R equations hold does _not_ imply that a function is holomorphic unless you also show that the real and imaginary parts of $f$ have continuous first-order partial derivatives.

Comment: Another note here is that in your notation above, $x$ and $y$ are part of the input, and $u$ and $v$ are part of the output. So I think that what you showed is that $f^{-1}$ satisfies the C-R equations, not that $f$ satisfies the C-R equations.

Comment: @JonathanPal how do I show $f$ satisfies the C-R equations? What are my explicit real and imaginary parts for $f$? I thought by setting $f(z)$ equal to $u_iv$ and expanding I found the explicit parts for $f$? No?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath, it looked like what you did what to solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ where $f(x + iy) = u + iv$, which gives you the explicit parts of $f^{-1}(u, v)$. In terms of the real and imaginary parts for $f$, I'm not aware of a simple expression in terms of $x$ and $y$ for $\sqrt{x+iy}$. In polar form ($re^{i \theta})$ it's simple but that's not quite what you're looking for.

Comment: @MyMathYourMath one approach here would be to calculate the explicit parts of $f$ and to show that they both have continuous partial derivatives and also satisfy the C-R equations, but as I mentioned, I'm not aware of a simple expression for the parts of $f$. If you're familiar with the inverse function theorem and the other notions mentioned by copper.hat's answer, then that is a simple approach.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Q = \{ z | \operatorname{re} z >0, \operatorname{im} z >0 \}$ and
define $\phi: Q \to D$ by $\phi(z) = z^2$. Since $\phi(r e^{i\theta}) = r^2 e^{2 i\theta}$, it is straighforward to check that $\phi$ is a bijection. Note that $\phi$ is analytic on $Q$ and $\phi'(z) \neq 0$ for $ \in Q$, hence the inverse function theorem shows that $\phi$ has a local analytic inverse, and since $\phi$ is a bijection the inverse is analytic on $D$.